# Look-Up Table using SIMD

Tags: c++, sse, simd

I have a big pixel processing function which I am currently trying to optimize using intrinsic functions.

Being an SSE novice, I am not sure how to tackle the part of the code which involves lookup tables.

Basically, I am trying to vectorize the following vanilla C++ code:

```
 //outside loop
const float LUT_RATIO = 1000.0F;

//in loop
float v = ... //input value
v = myLookupTable[static_cast<int>(v * LUT_RATIO)];
```

What I'm trying:

```
//outside loop
const __m128 LUT_RATIO = _mm_set1_ps(1000.0F);

//in loop
__m128 v = _mm_set_ps(v1, v2, v3, v4); //input values
__m128i vI = _mm_cvtps_epi32(_mm_mul_ps(v, LUT_RATIO)); //multiply and convert to integers
v = ??? // how to get vI indices of myLookupTable?
```

edit: ildjarn makes a point that demands clarification on my part. I am not trying to achieve speedup for the lookup table code, I am simply trying to avoid having to store the registers back to floats specifically for doing the lookup, as this part is sandwiched between 2 other parts which could theoretically benefit from SSE.

Comment: Who has you convinced that you can improve on `myLookupTable[static_cast<int>(v) * LUT_RATIO]`? There's no computation being performed here, why would SSE be applicable?

Comment: @ildjarn I am pretty sure I can't improve this part per se, but I am hoping to improve other parts of the function, and to avoid the penalty of moving back and forth between `__m128` and `float[4]` I must also vectorize this code.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you can wait until next year then Intel's Haswell CPUs will have AVX2 which includes instructions for gathered loads. This enables you to do e.g. 8 parallel LUT lookups in one instruction (see e.g. `VGATHERDPS`). Other than that, you're out of luck, unless your LUTs are quite small (e.g. 16 elements), in which case you can use `PSHUFB`.

Comment: Unfortunately my LUTs are 10000 elements large. Even if I were to wait for a new processor, it would be years until it would be legitimate to specify Haswell as a minimum cpu. :) Thanks for the info.

Comment: OK - if you can approximate your LUTs, e.g. with a polynomial then you may still get a win with SSE, otherwise I'm afraid you're stuck with scalar code.

Comment: Scalar code it is then. This is good news in a way, I can stop worrying about this part and go work on parts that might prove more optimizable.

Comment: Why wouldn't something like that work: _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*) LutIndex, _mm_cvtps_epi32(_mm_mul_ps(LUT_RATIO, floatData)));
       __m128 www = _mm_set_ps(myLUT[LutIndex[3]], myLUT[LutIndex[2]], myLUT[LutIndex[1]], myLUT[LutIndex[0]]);

Comment: @Drazick: it would work, but there is a lot of scalar code and multiple memory accesses hidden behind that `_mm_set_ps` intrinsic.

Comment: @PaulR, Is there a better way to do it using SSE? How would you do it with AVX?

Comment: Not really - you need AVX2 or AVX-512 for gathered loads.